# How to add a checked checkbox element into Div dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want to make a `JavaScript function`, which, after pressing a `button`, takes the list of `checkbox` elements with their content, **checks all** the `checkboxes`, creates a `div` element with these `checkboxes` and writes the result to the **`HTML` form.**

**Here is my code:**

```
function  confirmDrivers() {     
   $('#selectedList').find('.chk').prop("checked", true);
   var list = document.getElementById('selectedList').getElementsByTagName("li");
   var myForm = document.getElementById('formInput');
   var text = "<strong>Selected Drivers: </strong> <br><br>";
   var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
   myDiv.setAttribute("id","selectedInputDrivers");
   myDiv.style.overflowY = "auto";
   myDiv.style.maxHeight = "100px";
   myDiv.style.maxWidth = "250px";

   for (i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {                        
      myDiv.innerHTML = list[i].innerHTML+'<br>'+myDiv.innerHTML;                 
   }            
   $("formInput").find('.chk').prop("checked", true);
   myForm.innerHTML = myDiv.outerHTML + myForm.innerHTML;
   myForm.innerHTML = text + myForm.innerHTML;
}
```

Here is the HTML Div element with the list of checkbox elements. They also appear dynamically. Initially, Div is empty.

```
<div id = "selectedList" class = "col" style=" max-height:200px; max-width:500px;display: inline-block; background:#A8D9F1; overflow-y:auto">
<strong style="margin-right:10px">Selected List of Drivers</strong>
<input type="button" style="margin-right:10px" value="Remove All"  name="removeAllDr" onclick="removeAllDrivers()"  />
<input type="button" id="confirmD" value="Confirm"  name="confirm" onclick="confirmDrivers()"  />
<br><br>


</div>
```

And this is the HTML form, where I want my result to appear:

```
 <form id="formInput">    

</form>
```

The problem here is that it checks all the `checkboxes` in my list, but in the resulting **`HTML` form** they appear unchecked again. What is **wrong** with it? Thank you

Comment: Please add html too

Comment: Could you show us a working example of your code. It's difficult to see what could be wrong here from this JS alone

Comment: Can you create a http://codepen.io/ and add the link to your question

Comment: Calling `.prop()` doesn't change the HTML of the checkbox, it just changes it's current state.  You could try `.attr()` but I'm not sure if this will do it either.

Comment: You are aware that `setAttribute("id","selectedInputDrivers")` will cause duplicate `ID`'s... `ID`'s should be unique. Also if you were using `document.createElement()` for your checkboxes you could use `setAttribute("checked","checked")`

Comment: Oh, great!, `.attr()` has solved the problem. Thank you, Rik Lewis :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides replacing prop() to attr() as Rik Lewis correctly recommended you can alternately put the line

**$("formInput").find('.chk').prop("checked", true);**

at the bottom of the function and add the # character in front the selector id  like this:

```
function  confirmDrivers() {     
   $('#selectedList').find('.chk').prop("checked", true);
   var list = document.getElementById('selectedList').getElementsByTagName("li");
   var myForm = document.getElementById('formInput');
   var text = "<strong>Selected Drivers: </strong> <br><br>";
   var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
   myDiv.setAttribute("id","selectedInputDrivers");
   myDiv.style.overflowY = "auto";
   myDiv.style.maxHeight = "100px";
   myDiv.style.maxWidth = "250px";

   for (i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {                        
      myDiv.innerHTML = list[i].innerHTML+'<br>'+myDiv.innerHTML;                 
   }            
   myForm.innerHTML = myDiv.outerHTML + myForm.innerHTML;
   myForm.innerHTML = text + myForm.innerHTML;
   $("#formInput").find('.chk').prop("checked", true);
}
```

---

```js
     function confirmDrivers() {
       $('#selectedList').find('.chk').prop("checked", true);
       var list = document.getElementById('selectedList').getElementsByTagName("li");
       var myForm = document.getElementById('formInput');
       var text = "<strong>Selected Drivers: </strong> <br><br>";
       var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
       myDiv.setAttribute("id", "selectedInputDrivers");
       myDiv.style.overflowY = "auto";
       myDiv.style.maxHeight = "100px";
       myDiv.style.maxWidth = "250px";

       for (i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         myDiv.innerHTML = list[i].innerHTML + '<br>' + myDiv.innerHTML;
       }
       myForm.innerHTML = myDiv.outerHTML + myForm.innerHTML;
       myForm.innerHTML = text + myForm.innerHTML;
       $("#formInput").find('.chk').prop("checked", true);
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectedList" class="col" style=" max-height:200px; max-width:500px;display: inline-block; background:#A8D9F1; overflow-y:auto">
  <strong style="margin-right:10px">Selected List of Drivers</strong>
  <input type="button" style="margin-right:10px" value="Remove All" name="removeAllDr" onclick="removeAllDrivers()" />
  <input type="button" id="confirmD" value="Confirm" name="confirm" onclick="confirmDrivers()" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="test" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="test" />
    </li>
    <ul>
</div>
<form id="formInput">

</form>
```

Comment: Added a working code snippet.. Maybe you forgot the #?

Comment: I see now, probably that was the case. Thank you for the good explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="cblist">
    <input type="checkbox" value="first checkbox" id="cb1" /> <label for="cb1">first checkbox</label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="ok" id="btnSave" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
        addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
    });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
   var container = $('#cblist');
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;

   var html = '<input type="checkbox" id="cb'+id+'" value="'+name+'" /> <label for="cb'+id+'">'+name+'</label>';
   container.append($(html));
}
</script>
```